# How to insert a new array in an index but keep the number originally in the index?

Tags: java, arrays

I tried to insert a character into the array in the code below, it works but gets rid of the number in the position. How do I move the old element back a space.

```
public class MainArrays {
  public static int[] add(int[] arr, int val) {
      int[] newArray = Arrays.copyOf(arr, arr.length + 1);
      newArray[arr.length] = val;
      return newArray;
   }
   public static int[] del(int[] arr) {
      return Arrays.copyOf(arr, arr.length - 1);
   }
   public static int[] ins(int[] a, int pos, int num) {
    int[] result = new int[a.length];;
    for(int i = 0; i < pos; i++)
        result[i] = a[i];
        result[pos] = num;
    for(int i = pos + 1; i < a.length; i++)
        result[i] = a[i - 1];
    return result;
    }
   
  

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      int[] a = { 1, 2, 4 };
      System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
      a = add(a, 7);
      System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
      a = del(a);
      System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
      a = ins(a, 2, 3);
      System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
     
   }
}
```

```
Old Output
[1,2,4]
New Output
[1,2,3]
Desired Output
[1,2,3,4]
```

Comment: Hint: First create a new array with the correct length note the +1 to make it one bigger `int[] result = new int[a.length+1];`

Comment: @sorifiend It works but the output is at 0 instead of 4 and when I try to insert it in main it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two issues, first you need to increane the new array size by 1, note the +1 added here `int[] result = new int[a.length+1];`. The second issue is that you need to use `result.length` instead of `a.length` on the last loop otherwise it uses the original shorter array length so the last value will never copy, the correct usage is `for(int i = pos + 1; i < result.length; i++)`:

```
public static int[] ins(int[] a, int pos, int num) {
    int[] result = new int[a.length+1];
    for(int i = 0; i < pos; i++)
        result[i] = a[i];
    result[pos] = num;
    for(int i = pos + 1; i < result.length; i++)
        result[i] = a[i - 1];
    return result;
}
```

Now for the given input:

```
int[] a = { 1, 2, 4 };
a = ins(a, 2, 3);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
```

The output is as expected:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```